# Which is the correct way to insert data from dynamodb to elasticsearch via Logstash or lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, logstash

I want to insert data from multiple tables as a single document in AWS Dynamodb to Elasticsearch. Currently, I have set a trigger on one of my tables in Dynamodb and called a Lambda function which inserts the document in Elasticsearch. But recently I read this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-logstash-plugin-search-dynamodb-content-using-elasticsearch/) and got a bit confused to understand that which is the correct approach, using Logstash or Lambda function?

Comment: There's no single "right" way, it depends on your use case... Please tell us more about it.

Comment: I am storing files data, so these are split into multiple paragraphs which are being stored in a single table and a file metadata are stored in another table so whenever any update or insertion takes place, I want to combine all these data into a single document and insert into Elasticsearch. In lambda, I am not sure how to process this data and create one single document since my trigger is implemented on one table only.